Problema de repartición de unidades entre 2 tablas, mediante unas rutas establecidas
Necesito repartir el sobrante de la tabla sobrantes para cubrir el faltante de las tiendas de la tabla faltantes, todo esto respetando las rutas establecidas en la tabla rutas, y respetando la prioridad de menor a mayor.
Al final necesito obtener una tabla de como se repartió la mercancía.
No se puede repartir sobrante de más, ni cubrir más del faltante de las tiendas
CREATE TEMP TABLE faltantes (
  numTienda INT64,
  numcodigo INT64,
  numTalla INT64,
  numCodigoTalla INT64,
  faltante INT64
);

INSERT INTO faltantes (numTienda, numcodigo, numTalla, numCodigoTalla, faltante)
VALUES
  (11, 123456, 200, 123456200, 6),
  (12, 123456, 200, 123456200, 3),
  (13, 123456, 200, 123456200, 30),
  (16, 123456, 200, 123456200, 3),
  (18, 123456, 200, 123456200, 4),
  (21, 123456, 200, 123456200, 36),
  (22, 123456, 200, 123456200, 11),
  (24, 123456, 200, 123456200, 18),
  (25, 123456, 200, 123456200, 18),
  (27, 123456, 200, 123456200, 23);

CREATE TEMP TABLE sobrantes (
  numTienda INT64,
  numcodigo INT64,
  numTalla INT64,
  numCodigoTalla INT64,
  sobrante INT64
);

INSERT INTO sobrantes (numTienda, numcodigo, numTalla, numCodigoTalla, sobrante)
VALUES
  (1, 123456, 200, 123456200, 39),
  (3, 123456, 200, 123456200, 17),
  (6, 123456, 200, 123456200, 39),
  (7, 123456, 200, 123456200, 5),
  (20, 123456, 200, 123456200, 256);

CREATE TEMP TABLE rutas (
  tiendaOrigen INT64,
  tiendaDestino INT64,
  Prioridad FLOAT64
);
--------
INSERT INTO rutas (tiendaOrigen, tiendaDestino, Prioridad)
VALUES
(1, 8, 2),
(1, 18, 2),
(1, 7, 2),
(1, 21, 2),
(1, 16, 2),
(1, 15, 2),
(1, 4, 2),
(3, 7, 2),
(3, 12, 2),
(3, 20, 2),
(3, 11, 2),
(3, 27, 2),
(3, 18, 2),
(3, 15, 2),
(6, 15, 2),
(6, 8, 2),
(6, 20, 2),
(6, 22, 2),
(6, 11, 2),
(6, 12, 2),
(6, 27, 2),
(6, 7, 2),
(6, 21, 2),
(6, 13, 2),
(7, 3, 2),
(7, 20, 2),
(7, 16, 2),
(7, 28, 2),
(7, 6, 2),
(7, 8, 2),
(7, 18, 2),
(7, 15, 2),
(7, 12, 2),
(20, 11, 2),
(20, 15, 2),
(20, 7, 2),
(20, 21, 2),
(20, 4, 2),
(20, 2, 2),
(20, 3, 2),
(20, 18, 2),
(20, 6, 2),
(20, 12, 2),
(20, 8, 2),
(1, 12, 3),
(1, 24, 3),
(1, 13, 3),
(1, 22, 3),
(1, 27, 3),
(3, 13, 3),
(3, 24, 3),
(3, 22, 3),
(3, 4, 3),
(6, 24, 3),
(6, 4, 3),
(7, 27, 3),
(7, 22, 3),
(7, 11, 3),
(7, 24, 3),
(7, 4, 3),
(7, 13, 3),
(20, 24, 3),
(20, 13, 3),
(20, 22, 3),
(20, 28, 3),
(20, 16, 3),
(20, 27, 3),
(1, 28, 1),
(1, 11, 1),
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 25, 1),
(1, 3, 1),
(3, 6, 1),
(3, 28, 1),
(6, 2, 1),
(6, 18, 1),
(6, 25, 1),
(6, 1, 1),
(6, 3, 1),
(6, 16, 1),
(6, 28, 1),
(7, 2, 1),
(7, 25, 1),
(7, 21, 1),
(7, 1, 1),
(20, 25, 1),
(20, 1, 1),
(1, 20, 1.5),
(1, 6, 1.5),
(3, 1, 1.5),
(3, 21, 1.5),
(3, 2, 1.5),
(3, 8, 1.5),
(3, 25, 1.5),
(3, 16, 1.5);

Aqui genero las combinaciones posibles de repartos respetando las rutas y prioridades
WITH posibles_repartos AS (
    SELECT
     r.tiendaOrigen,
        r.tiendaDestino,
        r.Prioridad,
        f.numcodigo,
        f.numTalla,
     f.numCodigoTalla,
        f.faltante,
        s.sobrante
     FROM rutas r
    JOIN faltantes f
     ON r.tiendaDestino = f.numTienda
    JOIN sobrantes s
     ON r.tiendaOrigen = s.numTienda
    AND f.numCodigoTalla = s.numCodigoTalla
    ),

    Asigno las cantidades a repartir iterativamente 
    reparto_ajustado AS (
    SELECT
     tiendaOrigen,
     tiendaDestino,
     numcodigo,
        numTalla,
        numCodigoTalla,
     Prioridad,
     sobrante,
     faltante,
     LEAST(sobrante, faltante) AS cantidadRepartida,
     sobrante - LEAST(sobrante, faltante) AS sobranteRestante,
     faltante - LEAST(sobrante, faltante) AS faltanteRestante
    FROM posibles_repartos
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY tiendaDestino, numCodigoTalla
     ORDER BY Prioridad ASC, tiendaOrigen ASC
     ) = 1 
    ),

    Consolido las cantidades repartidas por tienda origen y destino
    resultado_final AS (
    SELECT
     tiendaOrigen,
     tiendaDestino,
        numcodigo,
     numTalla,
        numCodigoTalla,
        SUM(cantidadRepartida) AS totalRepartido
    FROM reparto_ajustado
    GROUP BY tiendaOrigen, tiendaDestino, numcodigo, numTalla, numCodigoTalla
    )

    tabla final
    SELECT *
    FROM resultado_final
    ORDER BY tiendaOrigen, tiendaDestino;

Al final este bloque me está repartiendo unidades de más de las que tiene como sobrante la tiendaorigen
